# C# Interface reference and this

Tags: c#

I am looking this code

```
interface IEven 
{
    bool IsOdd(int x);
    bool IsEven(int x);
}

class MyClass : IEven 
{
    bool IEven.IsOdd(int x) 
    {
        if((x%2) != 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public bool IsEven(int x) 
    {
        IEven o = this;
        return !o.IsOdd(x);
    }
}
```

which explains difference between explicit and implicit interface implementation.

How to write interface reference to the invoking object without this?

Comment: In this specific case you could put the logic in `IsEven` and use that from `IsOdd`.

Comment: @MartinVerjans That's not allowed since it's an explicit implementation.

Comment: @MartinVerjans That won't compile.

Comment: @MartinVerjans Yes,won't compile for sure!

Comment: @RichardRublev You probably should include that in the question as many will not know about that compilation issue.

Comment: @juharr Martins's solution won't compile,mine question was how to get new solution without this.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the duplicate ("without casting" vs "without `this`").  I can't think of any way to avoid the `this` keyword here, you need to change your expression type from `MyClass` to `IEven`.  The "duplicate" question lists all the forms you can use to achieve the dispatch; all involve the value keyword `this`.

Comment: `bool IEven.IsOdd(int x){ return !IsEven(x); } public bool IsEven(int x) { return x % 2 == 0; }`, but that's just for this case, otherwise you'll have to either do the casting or move the logic into a private method that both can use.